# FTP - 550 Failed to change directory

Tags: ftp

I am trying to write a remote file using FTP. I am using the [flysystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)  library to do so in PHP. It seems to be working well. However, when I try to write to a file in a specific location it gives me the chdir() error. To test this, I tried this on the FTP console.

```
[kbg@ip-192-0-1-118 ~]$ ftp
ftp> open 192.0.1.118
Connected to 192.0.1.118 (192.0.1.118).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (192.0.1.118:kbg):
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> pwd
257 "/"
ftp> cd /projects/test
550 Failed to change directory.
```

When I changed the following in the vsftpd.conf file, it seems to work well.

```
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=NO
```

I can even use the PHP library to write without any problem. What is the correct way to allow my user to write into a file in the /projects/test/t1.conf file?

Answer (score 8):

You got `chroot_local_user = No`
but it seems you do not have permission to traverse /projects/test .
You got to allow ftp_user traverse the directory above. To do that :-

```
setfacl -R -m u:ftp_user:rwx /projects/test
```

but if you got to change the directory contents, you got to better add ftp_user to let say ftp group by: -

```
usermod -a -G ftp ftp_user
```

You got to add ftp group if you haven't already.

Now change the group permissions and ownership for the directory by:-

```
chown -R :ftp /projects/test
chmod -R g+rwx /projects/test
```

And set the guid bit so that all the future files and directories inside it will allow ftp_user to access them.

```
chmod g+s /projects/test
```

Instead of group , the same procedure could be followed for user ownsership, permissions and bit but I assume if you are working with web directory, ownership will default to server user like www, www-data, apache, etc. , so you got to better work with groups here.

Or alternatively the secure option : -

`chroot_local_user = Yes` and you can bind the directory under ftp user's home directory. To do that :-

```
mount --bind /projects/test /home/ftp_user/projects_test
```

To get it persistent add the entry to fstab :-

```
/projects/test /home/ftp_user/projects_test none bind 0 0
```

and now you can traverse projects_test like it is /projects/test.

Comment: Perfect! Even 5 years after.

Comment: Perfect! Even 7 years after.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happened to me. I using java's org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.

My ftp account's root path is `/data/ftp`
When I want to change Working Directory to `/data/ftp/person`
And I invoke `ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/data/ftp/person");`

and ftp replay message: `550 Failed to change directory`.

And I found we should pass the sub directory instead of whole path to this method, but  we need to change.

So we should change directory like `ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("person");`